# I can't open a jar file

Tags: java, macos, jar

If through terminal I get a cant get permission error. If through double clicking I get a 'could not be launched - check the console for possible error messages'

Error from terminal

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/esotericsoftware/kryo/Serializer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: You could try using any .zip file opener. (I will admit that, mainly because I was watching a rom-com, my first thought when seeing the title of this question was "This must be a girl asking." Sorry.)

Comment: @NomadMaker - I have opened a zip file to get to my .jar file - Usually (until a few days ago) if I double clicked on this mac would launch said file with a jar opener programme. But as of yesterday this doesn't work and the above error shows.

Comment: I don't think you understand. A jar file is the same format as a zip file, and anything that will open a zip file will open a jar file. I do not know why your Mac has changed behavior.